# Can we let two child of Row widget to take width that they want (to show the content without overflow), and give the rest of space to the third child?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have three **Text** widgets to show in a **Row** (*firstname*, *middlename*, and the *lastname* respectively) in title of ListTile. **I want firstname and lastname to come must**, and middlename to take rest of the space, and if the space is not good enough to show the complete middle name, then *middlename* should show **ellipses**.

As you can see in the image below, that's the result I want to achieve.

[image]

Now I used Expanded with the middle name, and let other to have the widths the want.
by using the below code

```
ListTile(
    title : Row(
         children<widget> : [
             Text("First Name"),
             Expanded(
                 child : Text("Middle name", overflow : TextOverflow.ellipsis)
             ),
             Text("Last Name"),
         ]
    )
)
```

but by using the above code the middle name is taking extra spaces if the width of the screen is good enough to accommodate all the names, as you can see in the below image.

[image]

**What should I do to show first and last name must, but to give rest of the space to the middle name**?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will work for every situation but you can combine the flex attribute to create the effect:

```
  fullName(String firstName, String middleName, String lastName) {
    var style = TextStyle(
      fontSize: 36.0,
    );

    return Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(
          firstName,
          style: style,
        ),
        Expanded(
          flex: 1,
          child: Text(
            " $middleName ",
            style: style,
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          flex: 5,
          child: Text(
            lastName,
            style: style,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

And for this example:

```
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    fullName("Ricardo", "", "Markiewicz"),
    fullName("Ricardo", "F.", "Markiewicz"),
    fullName("Ricardo", "Federico", "Markiewicz"),
  ],
)
```

I get a result that looks like this:

[image]

To get a more exact result to your use case I think that there is not a widget that will fit this case. You may need to create your own widget that checks the available width and do the ellipsis in the middle of the string.

Comment: It's not working if the first name and last name is long it's overflowing!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Expanded you should use Flexible widget, so your final code should be

```
ListTile(
    title : Row(
         children: <Widget>[
             Text("First Name"),
             Flexible(
                 child : Text("Middle name", overflow : TextOverflow.ellipsis)
             ),
             Text("Last Name"),
         ]
    )
)
```

So basically `Expanded` widget take all the remaining space but `Flexible` will take only needed space.
Screenshot attached:
[image]

[image]

Comment: @MaazAftab It should work, as it's working at my end. I have attached screenshots as well.

Comment: yeah it's working in this case but if middle name is moderate in length it shows extra spaces that's my point

Comment: @MaazAftab Can you share a screenshot of case where it is not working, as I don't understand your point. If possible please use english words, so it will easy form me to find the problem. Also, sometimes ellipsis in Flutter not work properly, instead of character-wrap it wraps words, so try using small size words for testing.